# Apache mod rewrite RewriteCond to exclude exactly one URL

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I need an Apache rewrite condition to rewrite ALL URLs except /health_check. This works, but rewrites /health_check, and any incoming request. Can anyone suggest a modification to the below rules?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers would have worked well, had I not been using Symfony2, which rewrites all requests through app.php. Ultimately, I wanted to force https for traffic through an AWS Elastic Load Balancer. However, one route must remain accessible via http, to allow the ELB to perform it's "health check." In the end I just created a new file, health_check.html that could be accessed directly rather than routed through app.php, and changed my apache config to the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule !/health_check.html https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add another RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/health_check$
```